# Error: Missing class properties transform

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, ecmascript-next

`Error: Missing class properties transform`

`Test.js`:

```
export class Test extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
  }

  static contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }
```

`.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"],
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

`package.json`:

```
"babel-core": "^6.5.1",
"babel-eslint": "^4.1.8",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
"babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.5.2",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
"babel-register": "^6.5.2",
```

I have scoured the web and all fixes revolve around: Upgrading to babel6, switching the order of "stage-0" to be after "es2015". All of which I have done.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

OK, finally figured this out, in my `webpack.config.js` I had:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loaders: [
          'react-hot',
          'babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-0'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

`'babel?presets[]=stage-0,presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015'`

Has to be treated in the same way as `.babelrc`, switched stage-0 to be after es2015 and it compiles perfectly.

Comment: You don't need both. If you have a `.babelrc` you can ditch all of the params on your loader.

Comment: Did you simply solve your problem by adjusting your webpack.config.js? I'm facing the same problem but I'm using browserify and I can't get rid of it.

Comment: i am using browserify and using this oder "es2015", "react", "stage-0" worked for me. I put the config in the .babelrc.

Comment: Hey @speak, great find. But i suggest you to write down the correct config in this answer because i was first changed to your wrong config -_-

Comment: @lenny.myr you need to install 
https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/ if you are using browserify. And then on your gulp task update transform to 
        .transform('babelify', {presets: ['es2015', 'react','stage-0']})

Comment: I am using browserify and updated the order "es2015", "react", "stage-0" in .bablerc. Please make sure to have same order in package.json browersify.transform.presets OR for that matter it can be completely deleted if there is other transfrom required for browserify.

Answer (score 111):

You need to install [`@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties):

```
npm install @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties --save-dev
```

or

```
yarn add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties --dev
```

and add the following to your Babel configuration file - usually `.babelrc` or `babel.config.js`.

```
"plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"],
```

Comment: And with the new package, this is how the "plugins" section should look like:
`plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']`

Comment: this is already included in `@babel/preset-env`, so no need to install separately

Comment: do we need to create .babelrc or babel.config.js manually?

Answer (score 8):

Just in case anybody is actually still facing the same issue,
The following blog post did help me:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/typescript-and-babel-7/

In my case (babel 7.9.6, typescript 3.9.2, webpack 4.43.0) I had to do the following:

1. Run the following command:

   ```
   npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-typescript @babel/preset-env @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread
   ```
2. Create **.babelrc** file *(yes, I didn't have one before and it did work just fine)* with the following content:

   ```json
   {
       "presets": [
           "@babel/env",
           "@babel/preset-typescript"
       ],
       "plugins": [
           "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
           "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread"
       ]
   }
   ```

Comment: if you are using `@babel/preset-env` then the package `@babel/proposal-class-properties` is already included

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue when I put some arrow functions into one of my classes without thinking. Once I changed the arrow functions to regular function/method definitions the error was resolved.

Comment: While working with WebComponents and the `lit-element` library that helped.

Comment: It might be worth considering this fix if you didn't intend to include arrow functions as class properties, as they have some significant downsides after transpiling to ES2017. See https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1

Answer (score 3):

I had this same error and I ordered my plugins correctly in my .babelrc but it still persisted. Removing the preset parameters I defined in my webpack loader fixed it.

Former webpack config:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /.jsx?$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react']
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Working webpack config:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /.jsx?$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The fix in my case was defining **'transform-class-properties'** plugin in the options attribute of my **webpack.config.js**, i'm using babel V6

```
 rules:[
    .....,
    {
       test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
       exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
       loader: 'babel-loader',
       options: { plugins: ['transform-class-properties']}
    }
 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this error because I was using `stage-3` instead of `stage-0`.

Answer (score 2):

I also meet this error because of the using of env presets:

  `"presets": [ "react", "es2015", "stage-0", ["env", {
      "modules": false
    }]],`

and after I remove the env presets, it works well

Answer (score 0):

@speak is right, but you need to change the order

```js
loaders: [
  'react-hot',
  'babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-0'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem using [koa-react-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-react-view). Get inspired by these answers and finally fixed it with the following code in the `koa server.js`:

```js
const register = require('babel-register');

register({
    presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0'],
    extensions: ['.jsx']
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally discovered, To remove this error in Laravel-Mix project, add below code in `webpack.mix.js`

```
mix.webpackConfig({
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js?$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                    loaders: [
                        'babel-loader?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-0'
                    ]
                }
            ],
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Babel 7.4 or newer, `@babel/pollify` is deprecated.

Install `core-js`, `regenerator-runtime`, `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` and `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties` packages.

```
yarn add core-js regenerator-runtime @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties babel-plugin-transform-class-properties --dev
// or
npm install core-js regenerator-runtime @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties babel-plugin-transform-class-properties --save-dev
```

Then, add to `.babelrc` or `babel.config.js`

```
"plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"],
```

Finally, add this lines in your main js file:

```
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
```

**Taked from:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54490329/9481448

Answer (score -1):

Complete working solution --

1. Use "react-pdf": "^5.7.2" version
2. import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from "react-pdf";
3. Also add this inside your functional component

useEffect(() => { pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc =`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.js`;});

Comment: How is this even related to the question asked?

Answer (score -1):

If you're using create-react-app, you might add the babel specific configuration to your `package.json`:

```json
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        {
          "loose": true
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```