# Angular 2 - Forms : Get div element value

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to get the value of a `div` located inside a `<form>` the content of that `div` can be changed by the user as that `div` outputs a particular value (number of items in a shopping cart, the user can add, reduce the quantity of a certain item in that cart).

What I want to do is to get the value of that div, eg. in JavaScript we are doing something like that:

```
document.getElementById("idOfDiv").innerHTML
```

I want to do the exact same thing in **Angular 2**

P.S. My Angular 2 project is based on **JS**

Currently I have:

```
<div #nbOfItems>{{ (items()) }}</div>
```

Comment: can you use `#myDiv` over template element, and access that variable in component class?

Comment: I guess so, can you please give an example?

Comment: before that could you add some code here?

Comment: I've added what I have so far, which code you want me to add?

Comment: I understand you might be in a situation that requires this approach but for other AngularJS users I strongly suggest you rethink your app, any data you need should ideally be represented in an internal state/data object. For instance the more Angular-friendly approach would be to store the shopping cart as a Javascript object and bind its different values to the DOM, but using the data as a base for manipulation/reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the Element via [ElementRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html) in your component:

```
import {ElementRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

ngOnInit() {
 var el = this.element.nativeElement;
 console.log(el);
}
```

or with [ViewChild](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-var.html):

```
import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('nbOfItems') nbOfItems; 

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.nbOfItems.nativeElement.value);
}
```

Comment: I receive a syntax error: `Missing class properties transform.` Maybe that's only valid in TypeScript

Comment: the code should work. This is a babel error i think. Take a look here maybe this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35517245/error-missing-class-properties-transform

Comment: The second one, worked for me, but with this notation : `queries: {
    nbOfItems: new ViewChild('nbOfItems')
 }`