# ECMAScript 5 - Error Missing class properties transform

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-class

I am implementing the `Class extend` and i get this error *Missing class properties transform*.

The Component was

```
import React from ('react')

const Manna = React.createClass({,

  initVal: {
       likes: 10,
   }

   render() {
     // code
      return {
        // code
      }

   }

});

module.exports = Manna
```

and changed to

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Manna extends React.Component {

  InitVal: {
    likes: 10
  }

  render() {
     // code
    return {
       // code
    }

  }

};
```

This is my configuration in webpack.config.dev.js

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  loaders: 'babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-0',
  include: path.join(__dirname, 'client')
},
```

I have changed the loader following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35517245/error-missing-class-properties-transform)

Before it was `loaders: ['babel']`

I have also added to .babelrc the plugin

```
["transform-class-properties"],
```

This is the error in the console

```
 Missing class properties transform.
  15 |   // },
  16 | 
> 17 |   InitVal: {
     |   ^
  18 |     likes: 10,
  19 |     code: "2",
  20 |     size: 350,
```

I do not understand why it is complaining now for Missing class properties transform, what is wrong in the component?, everything was working fine before of these changes

Here a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Mannaio/48b32baee4bb820f7f2b1d62f4dc6274) with the full React component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with *=*

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Manna extends React.Component {

  InitVal = {
    likes: 10
  }

  render() {
     // code
    return {
       // code
    }

  }

};
```

Check [this](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/)

**UPDATE**

Since we are using `stage-0` and `transform-class-properties` is included in `stage-2`, we don't have to include it manually in `.babelrc` under `plugins`. The following configuration works fine: `"presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]`.

In the gist at line [5](https://gist.github.com/Mannaio/48b32baee4bb820f7f2b1d62f4dc6274#file-react-component-manna-L5) `InitVal` is written with an uppercase `i` while at line [39](https://gist.github.com/Mannaio/48b32baee4bb820f7f2b1d62f4dc6274#file-react-component-manna-L39) is written with a lowercase `i`: `initVal`. Additionally render method returns an Object Literal, which is invalid, a single child element as to be returned as explained [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#render).

[Here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes) is the official documentation for react components defined as es6 classes.

Comment: You should add a note that this isn't ES6 either.

Comment: Unexpected token now 
> 17 |   InitVal = {

Comment: se here the full component in the gist https://gist.github.com/Mannaio/48b32baee4bb820f7f2b1d62f4dc6274

Comment: I just notice that you are using `stage-0`, `transform-class-properties` is included in `stage-2`, so you don't have to include it manually in `.babelrc` under `plugins`. I have the following configuration and works fine: `"presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]`. Have you also tried to delete `node_modules` and run `npm install`?

Comment: yes i should have installed npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0, get different error now                                                                             var viewBoxParametersWidth = initVal.viewBoxParametersWidth;
                                   ^
ReferenceError: initVal is not defined, same gist https://gist.github.com/Mannaio/48b32baee4bb820f7f2b1d62f4dc6274

Comment: At line [5](https://gist.github.com/Mannaio/48b32baee4bb820f7f2b1d62f4dc6274#file-react-component-manna-L5) `InitVal` is written with an uppercase `i` while at line [39](https://gist.github.com/Mannaio/48b32baee4bb820f7f2b1d62f4dc6274#file-react-component-manna-L39) is written with a lowercase `i`: `initVal`. I also noticed that your `render` method returns an Object Literal, which is invalid, you have to return a single child element as explained [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#render)

Comment: grazie Matteo! I uppercase was not sensitive case but you point me to the right direction here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes, update the answer so i can accept it