# How to Fix "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null" error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I want to set up a simple Shopping Cart in React. I'm trying to have a drop down  menu with sizes for a clothing item. I set it up in my render but something is wrong and i get : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`.

This is my JSX:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


let cart = {price:0,item:"",size:""}

export default class Cart extends Component {
  handleClick(){
    e => {
      cart = {price:0,item:"userselection",size:"userselection"};
    }
    console.log(cart);
  } 

  itemSelection(){
    let userOrder = {price:0,item:"",size:""};
    let userItem = "";
    if (userItem == "pants1") {
      let itemPrice = 20.00;
    }

  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className='Webshop' id='Webshop'>
                <li>
                <img src="./gods.jpeg" width="350" height="350"></img>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick} id="addit">Add to cart</button>
            <select id="size" onChange={this.change} value={this.state.value}>
              <option value="medium">Medium</option>
              <option value="large">Large</option>
              <option value="x-large">X-large</option>
            </select>
            <img src="./gods.jpeg" width="350" height="350"></img>
            </li>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Is there something wrong with my Render that is returning a Null value?

EDIT

Since this is a due to a Null value, how could I fix this to get the dropdown menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason is, you didn't define the `constructor` and `state` variable and you are accessing `this.state.value`. First define the `state` like this:

```
constructor(){
   super();
   this.state = {value: ''}
}
```

You are using the `arrow function` in wrong way, use it like this:

```
handleClick = (e) => {
   cart = {price:0,item:"userselection",size:"userselection"};
   console.log(cart);
}
```

You didn't define the `change` method, define that also.

Write your component like this:

```
export default class Cart extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {value: ''}
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.change = this.change.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        cart = {price:0,item:"userselection",size:"userselection"};
        console.log(cart);
    } 

    change(e){
        this.setState({value: e.target.value})
    }

    itemSelection(){
        let userOrder = {price:0,item:"",size:""};
        let userItem = "";
        if (userItem == "pants1") {
           let itemPrice = 20.00;
        }
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className='Webshop' id='Webshop'>
                <li>
                    <img src="./gods.jpeg" width="350" height="350"></img>
                    <button onClick={this.handleClick} id="addit">Add to cart</button>
                    <select id="size" onChange={this.change} value={this.state.value}>
                        <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                        <option value="large">Large</option>
                        <option value="x-large">X-large</option>
                    </select>
                    <img src="./gods.jpeg" width="350" height="350"></img>
                </li>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason, using `handleClick = (e) => {` causes and error when using Webpack. `Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token`.

Comment: for that you can bind the function in the constructor, check the updated answer, it will no throw the error.

Comment: @feners for that you need to use babel-class transform properties, check this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35517245/error-missing-class-properties-transform

Answer (score 0):

The `select` element is requesting `this.state.value`. It seems that `this.state` is `null`, thus you're seeing that error when trying to access `null.value`.