# How to fix 'Module build failed: SyntaxError: Missing class properties transform.'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

In my reactjs component I have this code:

```
increment = () => {
     store.dispatch({type: 'INC'});
}
```

When I run npm start in the console I get:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Missing class properties transform.
```

I installed :

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties
```

And also added this to my .babelrc :

```
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties"
  ],

  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ],
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What is the content of your `npm start` script?

Comment: webpack-dev-server --progress --inline --hot

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this other post: [Error: Missing class properties transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35517245/error-missing-class-properties-transform) ?

I had a similar problem, and, as one of the comments on the accepted answer above suggests, I had the presets listed in both my `.babelrc` file and my `webpack.config`.  I removed the redundant options from my `webpack.config` and now it runs.