# Angular 5 TypeScript- including ES2015 code

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am working on angualar 5 app where I have to include [dmn-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dmn-js) library which doesn't have typings available. I followed the steps outlined in angular-cli [wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib) on how to go about including 3rd party libraries, specifically one outlined under heading - "If the library doesn't have typings available at @types/, you can still use it by manually adding typings for it:"

This is how my code now looks like after -

**src/typings.d.ts**

```
/* SystemJS module definition */
declare var module: NodeModule;
declare module 'dmn-js';
interface NodeModule {
  id: string;
}
```

**src/app/app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import * as DmnJS from 'dmn-js';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'DMN';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    var viewer = new DmnJS ({ container: 'body' });
    var dmnXML; //DMN 1.1 xml
    viewer.importXML(dmnXML, this.handleError);
  }

   handleError(err: any) {
    if (err) {
      console.warn('Ups, error: ', err);
    }else {
      console.log('rendered');
    }
  }

  load(): void {
    const url = '/assets/dish-decision.dmn';
    this.http.get(url, {
      headers: {observe: 'response'}, responseType: 'text'
    }).subscribe(
      (x: any) => {
        console.log('Fetched XML, now importing: ', x);
        //this.modeler.importXML(x, this.handleError);
      },
      this.handleError
    );
  }

  save(): void {
    //this.modeler.saveXML((err: any, xml: any) => console.log('Result of saving XML: ', err, xml));
  }

}
```

Now when I compile the code, I get below error. I am not sure what needs to be done to resolve the issue since I followed all steps.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/dmn-js-drd/lib/Viewer.js                                                                                                                                            
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (175:4)                                                                                                                                               
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.                                                                                                                                
|     additionalModules,                                                                                                                                                                    
|     canvas,                                                                                                                                                                               
|     ...additionalOptions                                                                                                                                                                  
|   } = options;                                                                                                                                                                            
|                                                                                                                                                                                           
ERROR in ./node_modules/dmn-js-shared/lib/base/Manager.js                                                                                                                                   
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (292:16)                                                                                                                                              
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.                                                                                                                                
|   }                                                                                                                                                                                       
|                                                                                                                                                                                           
|   _viewsChanged = () => {                                                                                                                                                                 
|     this._emit('views.changed', {                                                                                                                                                         
|       views: this._views,                                                                                                                                                                 
ERROR in ./node_modules/dmn-js-decision-table/lib/Viewer.js                                                                                                                                 
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (75:6)                                                                                                                                                
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.                                                                                                                                
|       modules,                                                                                                                                                                            
|       additionalModules,                                                                                                                                                                  
|       ...config                                                                                                                                                                           
|     } = options;                                                                                                                                                                          
|                                                                                                                                                                                           
ERROR in ./node_modules/dmn-js-literal-expression/lib/Viewer.js                                                                                                                             
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (77:6)                                                                                                                                                
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.                                                                                                                                
|       modules,                                                                                                                                                                            
|       additionalModules,                                                                                                                                                                  
|       ...config                                                                                                                                                                           
|     } = options;                                                                                                                                                                          
|                                                                                                                                                                                           

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Comment: Looks like you are using webpack but haven't told webpack to load `.js` files.

Comment: The problem is with loading the web pack. Maybe this link can help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469929/you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type-with-webpack-and-b?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I used angular-cli to create the project. I don't see webpack.config.js created by angular-cli. The wiki doesn't let webpack know about .js files separately.  I used npm install dmn-js to install libraries.

Comment: When using angular.cli webpack settings will be hidden for you. 
So you can use ng eject (but read before it) or use angular-cli.json section script. There you can include javascrpt files.

Comment: You should address this issue to the library owner. Serving es6 code as a library is not the best practice because most of the tools / setups are excluding node_modules from compilation and angular cli is one of them.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The lib owners have addressed this here - https://forum.bpmn.io/t/using-dmn-js-with-angular-5/2057/5?u=indusbull. They also provided an node module example here that transpiles code in es2015 using babel - https://github.com/bpmn-io/dmn-js-examples/tree/master/bundling. I tried all suggestions and all turned out to be futile so far.

Comment: Looking at your link https://github.com/bpmn-io/dmn-js-examples/blob/master/bundling/webpack.config.js - this is exactly what I was saying, they do not exclude node_modules in Babel config.

Comment: You can simply all this by importing the dist as `import * as DmnJS from 'dmn-js/dist/dmn-viewer.development';`, see if this helps

Comment: @TarunLalwani I get an error "TypeError: DmnJs is not a constructor"

Comment: The issue seems that the spread destructing is not working and the file is also js and not ts. The default tsconfig processes ts only making it to process this module didn't help as it created another error

Comment: Try to add dmn-js to your angular-cli.json. take a look at this post : https://forum.bpmn.io/t/using-dmn-js-with-angular-5/2057/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Angular-cli wiki tells how to add, as you have followed it already,now
>   you can access the third party lib, but here dmn-js requires plugins
>   which can support( spread operators,and other internal
>   transforms,etc.). and dmn-js uses babel [if you observe that it is
>   having .babelrc files in each folder of dmn* ].

In order to support the dmn-js we need to configure webpack.
After spending decent amount of time here is the result :

[image]

**In your.Component.ts**

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient ){
    this.http.get('../assets/val.xml',{responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(x=>{
     var xml= x; // my DMN 1.1 xml
     //var myContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('canvas');
    var viewer = new Viewer({
      container: '.canvas'
    });

    viewer.importXML(xml, function(err) {
     console.log('*********************');
      if (err) {
        console.log('error rendering', err);
      } else {
        viewer
        .getActiveViewer()
        .get('canvas')
          .zoom('fit-viewport');
      }
    });
    });
```

**In your.Component.html**

```
<body >
<div class="canvas" style="width:100vh;height:100vh ;padding-left:100px"></div>
  </body>
```

> **In Webpack.config.js (use ng eject , if not exists)**
>    Add a rule in module ->  rules

```
 { test: /\.js$/, 
        exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(dmn-js|dmn-js-drd|dmn-js-shared|dmn-js-decision-table|table-js|dmn-js-literal-expression|diagram-js)\/).*/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',query: {presets: ["react","es2015","stage-0"]} 

      }
```

**In index.html add stylesheet links**

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/dmn-js@4.3.0/dist/assets/dmn-js-drd.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/dmn-js@4.3.0/dist/assets/dmn-js-decision-table.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/dmn-js@4.3.0/dist/assets/dmn-js-literal-expression.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/dmn-js@4.3.0/dist/assets/dmn-font/css/dmn.css">
```

Typings.d.ts -> you have added already !!

**Install the depenencies:**

> npm i --save-dev babel-plugin-inferno
>   babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread
>   babel-plugin-transform-class-properties
>   babel-plugin-transform-object-assign

Hope this helps !!!

Ref1: https://github.com/bpmn-io/dmn-js-examples/tree/master/bundling

Ref2: [Error: Missing class properties transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35517245/error-missing-class-properties-transform)

Ref3:https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2902

Comment: for your reference created git repo: https://github.com/HariDongli/dmn-js-angular-stack !!!

Comment: This is great! -) Thank you very much for taking time to resolve. It is working now. I had to download additional npm dependencies to make it work  -
npm install --save-dev babel-loader babel-preset-stage-2 babel-preset-es2015

Comment: Thanks to you !!!, came across the babel , haven't used so far !!!
you can add this to forum of dnm-js https://forum.bpmn.io/t/using-dmn-js-with-angular-5/2057/6 :)

Comment: I actually just posted ref to your solution there :-)