# Babel 7 - ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

I have an application that is a node backend and a react frontend.

I get the following error when i try to build/run my node application.

Node: `v10.13.0`

**Error:**

> dist/index.js:314
>         regeneratorRuntime.mark(function _callee(productId) {
>         ^
>
> ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": [    [
        "@babel/preset-env", {
          "targets": {
            "node": "current"
          },
        }
      ], "@babel/preset-react"],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
{
        mode: "development",
        entry: "./src/index.js",
        target: "node",
        externals: [nodeExternals()], // in order to ignore all modules in node_modules folder
        stats: {
            colors: true
        },
        devtool: "source-map",

        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
            filename: "index.js",
            sourceMapFilename: "index.js.map"
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    enforce: "pre",
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: "eslint-loader",
                },
                {
                    test: /\.m?js$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "babel-loader",
                        options: {
                            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
        },
        node: {
            __dirname: false,
            __filename: false,
        },

        "plugins": [
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
            new WebpackShellPlugin({
                onBuildStart: [],
                onBuildEnd: ["nodemon dist/index.js"]
            }),

        ]

    },
```

**package.json**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "connect": "^3.6.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "hellojs": "^1.17.1",
    "i18n-iso-countries": "^3.7.8",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "request-promise-native": "^1.0.5",
    "serve-static": "^1.13.2",
    "vhost": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.1.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.6.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.10.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "extract-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.26.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2",
    "webpack-shell-plugin": "^0.5.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 200, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

If you are using Babel 7.4.0 or newer, then `@babel/polyfill` has been [deprecated](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill). Instead, you will want to use the following at the top of your main js file (likely index.js or similar):

```
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
```

Install these packages either with npm:

```
npm install --save core-js
npm install --save regenerator-runtime
```

or with yarn:

```
yarn add core-js
yarn add regenerator-runtime
```

**Original Answer:**

I just encountered this problem and came across the following solution:

In package.json I had `@babel/polyfill` as a dependency. However, in my index.js (My main js file) I had neglected to place the following line at the the top:

`import '@babel/polyfill'`

Once I imported it, everything worked fine.

I did not need to install babel-runtime as other answers are suggesting.

Comment: You, my friend, deserve a cookie! I second there's no need to install any runtime

Comment: wow, this is the only up-to-date answer about this on the entire internet

Comment: Would still be interesting to know why at all this runtime is needed. Why can't it transform async functions to simple promises?

Comment: Importing `core-js/stable` through `import "core-js/stable";` generates a very big bundle. Is there a way to tell Babel to only polyfill what it's needed?

Comment: Where should I put the import statements?

Comment: I just want to add that the import statements must be loaded first in order to work!

Comment: @tonix `import 'core-js/features/promise';`

Comment: @ford04's solution is more in-depth, lists all the possible solutions, and cites sources.

Comment: Do we still need the `regenerator-runtime/runtime`?

Comment: A working configuration is a moving target with a lot of byzantine bits. "Babel" seems more aptly named every time I update a dependency.

Answer (score 117):

## Babel 7.4.0 and later

There are two main configurations - one for apps and one for libraries.

### Option 1: App

**When to use:** ✔ for applications ✔ *global* scope polyfills ✔ smallest bundle size ✔ selective inclusion via [`targets`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#targets) ✔ No need to process  `node_modules` for polyfills

```json
"presets": [
  [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    {
      "useBuiltIns": "usage", // alternative mode: "entry"
      "corejs": 3, // default would be 2
      "targets": "> 0.25%, not dead" 
      // set your own target environment here (see Browserslist)
    }
  ]
]
```

Install dependencies:

```
npm i --save-dev @babel/preset-env

npm i regenerator-runtime core-js // run-time dependencies
// regenerator-runtime: transform (async) generators and `async`/`await`
// core-js: other ECMAScript features like Promise, Set, etc.
```

[`@babel/preset-env`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env) *selectively* includes polyfills for `targets`, specified by a [Browserslist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist) query. There are two modes - try `usage` first (more convenient), else `entry` (more flexible and robust):

- **useBuiltIns ['usage'](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#usebuiltins-usage)**: no need to `import` anything manually. All polyfills are added automatically based on their *code usage* in a file.
- **useBuiltIns ['entry'](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#usebuiltins-entry)**: Add these `import` entries *once* (!) in your app - akin to `@babel/polyfill`:

  ```
  import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
  import "core-js/stable"; // or more selective import, like "core-js/es/array"
  ```

#### Extension

For advanced cases, you might use `@babel/transform-runtime` (dev) and `@babel/runtime` (run-time) **only** for [Babel helpers](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-runtime#helpers) to reduce bundle size a bit more - called helper aliasing.

### Option 2: Library

**When to use:** ✔ for libraries ✔ *no* global scope pollution ✔ includes *all* polyfills, not selective ✔ bigger bundle size neglectable

```json
"plugins": [
  [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
    {
      "regenerator": true,
      "corejs": 3
    }
  ]
]
```

Install compile-time and run-time dependencies:

```
npm i --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-runtime // only for build phase

npm i @babel/runtime // runtime babel helpers + just regenerator runtime
// OR (choose one!)
npm i @babel/runtime-corejs3 
// also contains other JS polyfills (not only regenerator runtime)
// depends on core-js-pure ("ponyfills"/polyfills that don't pollute global scope)
```

See  [`@babel/plugin-transform-runtime`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-runtime), [`@babel/runtime`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-runtime), [`@babel/runtime-corejs`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-runtime#corejs).

#### Extension

You can additionally use `@babel/preset-env` for syntax transpilation only, with [`useBuiltIns: false`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#usebuiltins). As the library option does not use global polyfills, you might want to transpile `node_modules` as well - see the [`absoluteRuntime`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-runtime#absoluteruntime) option.

### Closing notes

- **Breaking Change**: [@babel/polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-polyfill) is deprecated starting with [Babel 7.4.0](https://babeljs.io/blog/2019/03/19/7.4.0).
- **Legacy**: If you can't switch to `core-js@3`, set [`corejs`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#corejs) option to `2` (see [migrations](https://babeljs.io/blog/2019/03/19/7.4.0#migration-from-core-js-2)). Install `@babel/runtime-corejs2` in case of option 2 (`@babel/plugin-transform-runtime`).
- [Excellent summary in #9853](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9853#issuecomment-619587386) by Jovica Markoski
- Currently, the library approach [doesn't take selective targets into account](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/10008) - meaning you take locally scoped polyfills at the price of bigger bundle size (including *all* polyfills).
- [babel-polyfills](https://github.com/babel/babel-polyfills) is a new, *experimental* approach to inject different polyfills (not just `core-js`) with different strategies.
- This also allows to [selectively include locally scoped polyfills](https://github.com/babel/babel-polyfills/blob/main/docs/migration.md#core-js3).

Answer (score 57):

There is already a [very good answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53736090/2832282) (originally posted on the Babel6 question) which I will just translate to Yarn. Basically, you need babel runtime (NOT as a dev dependency) and the plugin transform-runtime

```
yarn add @babel/runtime 
yarn add -D @babel/plugin-transform-runtime
```

And, in .babelrc, add:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
    "plugins": ["@babel/transform-runtime"]
}
```

Comment: This hint actually saved me. I was trying with DEV dependency and it didn't work.
Could you please explain WHY it is working now :)

Comment: @babel/runtime is needed as a dependency for your code to run
@babel/plugin-transform-runtime is needed when babel compiles your code

Comment: Considering the result, is there any difference between your method and the accepted answer?

Answer (score 26):

I had this error in my `react` project with `webpack 4` and this was preventing the whole project to get rendered.

This is how I solved it:

Install `plugin-transform-runtime`:

```
npm install @babel/plugin-transform-runtime -D
```

Add `plugin-transform-runtime` to the plugin's list in the `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/transform-runtime"]  // <= Add it here
  ]  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For me worked:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          esmodules: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
}
```

Comment: I'd love to read more about why this works! (And it did work for me as well.)

Comment: @AdamEasterling I would like to give you more information but sadly I can't. I searched many hours for a solution and tried a lot of approches but I don't know where I saw this and why this works.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this error when I imported babel-polyfill directly into the file that shows the error, for example, the error says "ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined at /dist/models/usersSchema.js", so I use this in my usersSchema.js file:

`require("babel-polyfill");`

(you can use `import "babel-polyfill";`as well)

Comment: babel-polyfill is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using @babel/runtime at version 7.18 or greater.

I found the explanation for this error and the solution here:
https://github.com/ant-design/pro-components/issues/5273#issuecomment-1133843012

Answer (score -1):

You will need to have the **regeneratorRuntime**.

Install this two packages -  **babel-plugin-transform-regenerator** and **babel-polyfill**

Add the following Babel configuration via `.babelrc`

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-regenerator"]
}
```

Comment: I think the other thing to do is to install `babel-polyfill` and require it at the topmost level of the application- `import 'babel-polyfill';`

Comment: Using babel 7 with `yarn add -D @babel/polyfill @babel/transform-regenerator` and adding `"@babel/transform-regenerator"` to my babelrc plugins did not work

Comment: This solved my issue

Answer (score -4):

**React.js Users**

If this issue faced you while using react (specifically while trying to use **Async/Wait**), then **Valentino Gagliardi** provided a detailed approach on [his blog](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/await-react/) regarding how to address this issue