# Babel 7 : regeneratorRuntime is not defined error

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I have an app that has node js in the backend.
in the dev side it is working fine. but in the prod with the built/compiled code, I got this error
ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54490329/8857703) but it is not working for me

babel.config.json

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread", "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
}
```

the entry file server.js  that calls the db connection file

```
import "core-js/stable"
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime"
require("dotenv").config()
import db from "./db"

const init = async () => {
  try {
    await db()
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err)
  }

  const opts = {
    port: process.env.PORT || 4000,
    cors: {
      origin: process.env.FRONTENDURL,
      credentials: true
    }
  }

  const server = require("./graphql/index")

  server.start(opts, t => {
    console.log(`server is up ${opts.port}`)
  })
}

init()
```

the db file where the error is originated

```
const mongodb = require("mongodb")

export default () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mongodb.connect(process.env.CONNECTIONSTRING, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, client) {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err)
      }
      module.exports = client
      return resolve()
    })
  })
}
```

also the build script in packagejson

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "babel src --out-dir dist --copy-files",
  },
```