# Missing class properties transform - REACT 18 - Create react app

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app created with create-react-app

I have imported a library I created using class syntax

I am getting the following error:

SyntaxError: ....RequestBody.js: Missing class properties transform.
35 |
36 | class RequestBody {

> 37 |     [FIELD_NAMES.INTERFACE_NAME] = "PRE_SALE_CHECK";
> |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> 38 |     [FIELD_NAMES.FROM] = "DAVE SHEEPLE";
> 39 |     [FIELD_NAMES.TO] = "MISTER JONES";
> 40 |

I have tried installing **babel-plugin-transform-class-properties**

and some other similar suggestions but none worked.

the project itself runs perfectly.

assistance is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35517245/error-missing-class-properties-transform

Comment: Yes, i have, it did not help